# Generate Dynamic Query for Multi Select Query in JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm very new for JasperServer.
Now I want to create a complex report that verify the right of Admin User and Normal User.

Example:
I have many branches of company, and I want to create one report that retrieve data only belong to the branch which belong to user.

Scenario:
-Admin User can see data of all branches, so in the Multi-Select Box, should show all Branch Name.
-Normal User can see data of the branch belong to that user, so in the Multi-Select Box, should show only Branch Name that belong to that user.

Please advise me, or send me an example to do it.

Thank so much before hand.
LeeJava

Comment: You need to accept some of the answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the username as parameter. In the mutiselect query you can use the username to fetch the desired data.